# What is the best way to ban bad actors?

Tags: php, nginx, iptables

I have a PHP application that encounters 2 types of bad actors:

1. Those scanning for vulnerabilities (either SQL injection, XSS or trying to request nonexistent URLs like /phpmyadmin or /webmail or some such)
2. Comment spammers.

The stack is Ubuntu 12.04 + nginx + PHP (FPM)

What I'd like to do is set up a process that can ban these bad actors by dropping their IP address when it detects a pattern of abuse. How should I do this?

Some examples of patterns would be:

1. More than 2 comments in 1 minute (detected either by nginx or PHP)
2. More than 2 comments in 10 minutes that each have URLs in them. (detected by nginx or PHP)
3. Requests made to phpmyadmin (needs to be detected by nginx)
4. Weird parameters passed to search/comment system. e.g. \' or OR 1=1'-- (I'd love to get a list of such common SQL injection patterns)

So the question is -- how to detect these patterns in nginx/PHP and how to set up a process that can ban the IP addresses of these actors?

PS - To be honest, I'm unsure how to best tag this question so please re-tag as appropriate.